# ¿Cómo puedo cargar en un controllador la clase \Predis\Client mediante inyección de dependencia?

Tags: controller, symfony4, inyeccion-de-dependencias, redis

He instalado en el proyecto las siguientes dependencias:

```
composer req symfony-bundles/redis-bundle
```

`composer require predis/predis`

El fichero sb_redis.yaml lo he actualizado con los datos de la variable de entorno REDIS_URl.

Y estoy intentando acceder a la clase de `Predis\Client` desde el método del controlador, pero me errores.

Solo he conseguido que me funcione así:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use App\Entity\AEQLogin;
use Predis\Client ;


class LoginRequestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/V0/login/Authenticate", name="login_request", methods={"get"})
     */
    public function login_authenticate(Request $request )
    {

        $redis = new RedisClient(getenv('REDIS_URL'));
        $redis->set('name' ,  'esto es un nombre');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo, después de buscar los servicios disponibles con este comando:
`php bin/console debug:autowiring redis`

He cambiado

`use Predis\Client ;`

por

`use SymfonyBundles\RedisBundle\Redis\ClientInterface;`

Y en el método:

```
<?php
public function login_authenticate(Request $request, ClientInterface $client )
    {

        $redis = $client;
        $redis->connect();
```